# Notebook will not run for values involving Pi

Tags: plotting

I have the following root finding function that should plot the V-field of a particle at a retarded time. ContourPlot will generate a plot for any t value that does not involve Pi, but when I try to plot for any $t = k\pi$ it does not want to generate the plot in a reasonable amount of time (I waited almost 5 minutes for one). Is this a reasonable amount of time to wait? Should I be waiting longer?

```
Bisection[F_, l_, r_, eps_] := 
 Module[{xl, xr, xm}, xl = l; xr = r; xm = (xl + xr/2);
  While[Abs[F[xm]] > eps, If[F[xm] F[xr] < 0, xl = xm, xr = xm]; 
   xm = (xl + xr)/2;];
  Return[xm] ]

Vfield[x_, y_, z_, t_, w_] := Module[{r, F, tr, R, V}, 
  r = {x, y, z}; 
  F[X_] := (t - X) - Norm[r - w[X]]; 
  tr = Bisection[F, -10, t, 10^-10]; 
  R = Norm[r - w[tr]]; 
  V = 1/R; 
  Return[V]]
s[t_] := {0, 0.05 Cos[5 t], 0};
ContourPlot[Vfield[x, y, 0, Pi, s], {x, -1, 1}, {y, .1, 1}]
```

Comment: Are you implying that this runs for values other than t=k Pi?

Comment: As I have tested it, it runs for any rational number, or any pi - (decimal number)

Comment: So it runs if you replace Pi by N[3 Pi] in the final line. It needs to have machine precision numbers as input (and not exact quantities like Pi).

Comment: Aha. I had tried Pi. but that didn't seem to fix it. I'll edit it to include N[3 Pi].